# Creating TestCase and adding attachment using Pyral

Tags: python, rally, pyral

I am trying to create a TestCase and then add an attachment to the TestCase. Currently i can successfully create a TestCase, but when I go to add the attachment I get 0 errors but no attachments are added. Here is my code:

```
import sys, os
import datetime
from pyral import Rally, rallyWorkset, RallyRESTAPIError

def main():
    rally = Rally("rally1.rallydev.com", 
    apikey="_myKey", workspace="myWorkspace", 
    project="myProject", verify_ssl_cert=False)
    rally.enableLogging("rally.history.showstories")

    query_criteria = 'FormattedID = "US622745"'
    response = rally.get('UserStory', query=query_criteria, instance=True)
    target_project = rally.getProject()

    timen = datetime.datetime.now()
    testcase_fields = {
         "Project"     : target_project.ref,
         "WorkProduct" : response.ref,
         "Name"        : "Automated Test Generation -- " + str(timen),
         "Method"      : "Automated",
         "Type"        : "Acceptance"
       }
    testcase = rally.put('TestCase', testcase_fields)
    print(testcase.details())

    try:
        attachment = rally.addAttachment(testcase.ref, "t2.txt")
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    sys.exit(0)
```

Everything works as expected up to the try block. The TestCase is successfully created for the given user story, but adding the attachment doesnt work, 0 errors though. Do I have to do something else following `rally.addAttachment()` ? The documentation is really rough for me to read and understand.

attachment is a boolean with value False, even though the documentation specifies it should return an attachment item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. `rally.addAttachment(testcase.ref, "t2.txt")` returns a boolean if it cannot find the artifact. Using `rally.addAttachment(testcase.FormattedID, "t2.txt")` works though.